# how to show errors of broken links in the Firefox Developer Tools?

Tags: html, debugging, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I tried to detect in my Firefox Developer Tools errors of loading some local resource files like

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">`

(when correct path to file is css/styles.css), but haven't seen any error messages in his console.
Maybe there are some options/settins, for to activate such behavior?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to get to know when requests are broken, i.e. result in a 404 HTTP status code.

1. Web Console

   The *Console* panel logs network requests when you enable the *Requests* filter.

   [image: Requests filter within the Web Console]

   Once the filter is enabled and the page reloaded, you'll see all network requests logged within the console. The failed ones will be shown in red and the 404 status code can be seen at the end of the line.

   [image: Failed network request within the Web Console]
2. Netmonitor

   The *Network* panel is the main place to check for any kind of information related to network requests. Similar to the *Console* panel it lists all the network requests made by a page, though in their the status code is shown at the start of the line instead of the end.

   [image: Failed network request within the Netmonitor]

*Important note:* Both places only list actual network requests executed by the page itself like `<link href="">` asked here or caused by user interactions. They do not *detect* broken links in the sense of `<a href="">` links referring to a non-existing resource.